# Load a .sav file in ENVI

Tags: remote-sensing, envi

I have a 23-band .sav file that I need to load in ENVI.  The 23 bands are 23 time points of MODIS NDVI data.  I ultimately want to run a classification on this data.  I have been using Data Manager to load the .sav file, but have only been able to load three bands at a time (RGB).

How can I load the ENTIRE 23-band file at once?

Answer (score 2):

Use restore procedure in IDL and then save it to ENVI binary file.
the code can like this:

```
envi,/restore_base_save_files
envi_batch_init
restore,'e:\ndvi.sav'  ;this can get variable ndvi,for example
ENVI_WRITE_ENVI_FILE,ndvi,OUT_NAME='e:\ndvi.dat'
envi_batch_exit
```

ndvi.dat can then be opened by ENVI.

Comment: It might be useful to provide a more detailed answer.